# On Mobile browser redirect / href autoclick does not work for href sms value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I wanted to redirect the page after the page loads. This work well with other href value like http link.

But it does not work for sms value.

```
<a id="action" href="sms:123456?body=ABCD 9876">SUBMIT</a>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'sms:1553?body=YTV'; }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Probably considered a security feature.

Comment: No, it's not a security feature. There must be a solution to this.

Comment: Why not? What makes you think I would want websites to trigger anything like this automatically on my system?

Comment: My Friend, that's the functionality we need for our marketing referral program

Comment: So you think it can’t be a security feature, simply based on that you “need it” …?

Comment: Is there mentioned anywhere on the web?